# how to do record count for different dataframe write without action using sparkListener?

Tags: apache-spark

Need to know the count of the dataframe after write without invoking additional action

I know using spark listener we can calculate like below. But Below code getting called for all task completed. Say i have dataframe1 and dataframe 2
for both dataframe write of each task `onTaskEnd` getting called. so i need a flag to segregate this call  for dataframe1 and datafarme2 to increase counter.

```
    var dataFrame_1_counter = 0L
    var dataFrame_2_counter = 0L
```

sparkSession.sparkContext.addSparkListener(new SparkListener() {

```
 override def onTaskEnd(taskEnd: SparkListenerTaskEnd) {
             synchronized {
               if(`isDataFrame1Call`){ // any way for isDataFrame1Call?
               dataFrame_1_counter += taskEnd.taskMetrics.outputMetrics.recordsWritten
               }else{
                 dataFrame_2_counter += taskEnd.taskMetrics.outputMetrics.recordsWritten  
               }
             }
           }
```

Need `isDataFrame1Call` flag. is there any way?

Comment: Hi - Do you really need that? I don't think you will ever write multiple dataframes at same time in threads. You can have 3 variables `var df_counter = 0L, var df1_counter = 0L and var df2_counter = 0L`. Now, use `df_counter` in listener and before you initiate write for `df2` you can capture the `df1` count in `df1_counter` and re-initiate `df_counter = 0L`. Why to put overhead on listener as it will stop all future tasks.

Comment: Badly need this requirement.  same session is shared across multiple writes. write could possibly happen at same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solved by using jobgroup setting for each thread in spark

Comment: can you provide more details on how you have done this?